# Youtube videos become out of sync with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, internet-explorer

While watching youtube videos, slowly but surely they become out of sync. By pressing progress bar ticker and dragging it to, for example, same position - audio sync issue is fixed, but, after a while it becomes out of sync again. The longer you watch the video without dragging the ticker, more out of sync it becomes.

This problem occurs while trying to watch youtube videos with chrome. I have also tried to use chrome canary builds, but same issue appears. Internet Explorer doesn't have this issue for me.

Any ideas?